# Search and Connect to Bluetooth device in Windows 8/8.1 Store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, bluetooth, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I need to search and connect to a Bluetooth device using a Windows store app.
I am using XAML/C# and Windows 8.1. The device supports RFCOMM.

What I have done so far:

If I pair the device to my system and then search for the device using

```
var devicesInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
```

I get the Bluetooth Device, however is there a way to find the device when its still not paired.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that (in Windows 8.1). You have to pair your device first, otherwise the offered service won't show up in the list returned by .FindAllAsync().