# List and connect to Bluetooth devices

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth, windows-8.1

I'm tryiing to make my Windows tablet app communicate with an other device via Bluetooth.

First I want to scan for devices, then i want to connect to the choosen device.

I've made a simple test app: Blank front page and added a button and a listboxto it. Then I've tried the following code witch I've forund else where here on SO:

```
    ListBox1.Items.Clear();

    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(device);
    }
```

But the list is just empty

Then I've tried to just enum devices and filtered out unwanted devices:

```
var list = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync();
var uniqueList = new HashSet<string>();
var terminators = new List<string>() { "Audio", "Mixer", "Mic", "Realtek", "Usb", "Gmail,", "Line in", "Lyd", "Display", "surface", "@" };

foreach (var element in list)
{

    var strToken = element.Name.ToUpper();

    if (!uniqueList.Add(strToken))
        continue;

    var contains = false;

    foreach (var word in terminators)
        if (strToken.Contains(word.ToUpper()))
            contains = true;


    if (!contains)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(element.Name);
}
```

But that doesn't give any meanfull list.

I have a feeling I'm doing ti wrong. Please helt me back on track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just got a little wiser, ive forund an other SO question telling me that it is not posible.

[Search and Connect to Bluetooth device in Windows 8/8.1 Store apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232205/search-and-connect-to-bluetooth-device-in-windows-8-8-1-store-apps?rq=1)

So the solution for listing is:

1) Pair your devices

2) List them :

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear();

    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));

    foreach (var device in devices)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(device);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the device capabilities yet? You have to define the Id and Function type yourself.

Useful link: [How to set device capabilities.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263090.aspx)

```
 <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
  <m2:Device Id="any">
    <m2:Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"/>
  </m2:Device>
</m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Furthermore, it is true that you cannot connect unpaired devices. (Windows appears to not support it.)