# C# - How connect to Xiaomi Smart Scale with Bluetooth

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, bluetooth

I Need to connect to [Xiaomi Smart Scale](http://www.mi.com/en/scale/) with Bluetooth in C#

Is this possible ?

Comment: @Sid TnQ 
I have not ever tried anything
And no idea how to start
The company also does not answer

Answer (score 0):

I see that some people on github already have made a few projects to access it (JavaScript, Android, iOS specifically), but I see nothing for C#.

So I'd say it's definitely possible. But maybe not that easy.

You could try to port [this little JavaScript project](https://github.com/dermike/xiaomi-smart-scale-app/blob/master/index.js) to C# and see for yourself.

edit: [some insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120882/list-and-connect-to-bluetooth-devices) about finding the actual bluetooth device. It most likely will have to be paired to the client machine already.

Comment: thank you @Kilazur
How should this javascript code be used? 
How do this JavaScript can be connect to Bluetooth?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but for what I gather it simply lists every connected bluetooth devices with a module named [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble), and read data for all of them. Only way to know for sure is to try it.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of searching I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mL9B8wuEdms) video 
I discovered MI_SCALE Bluetooth device

[discovered MI_SCALE Bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPiom.jpg)

with code 880f10a0dd92 and Command

> node peripheral-explorer.js 880f10a0dd92

Base on video Connected smart scale and receive data :

```
    > peripheral with ID 880f10a0dd92 found
  Local Name        = MI_SCALE
  Manufacturer Data = 5701880f10a0dd92
  Service Data      = [object Object]
  Service UUIDs     = 181d
  services and characteristics:
  1800 (Generic Access)
  2a00 (Device Name)
    properties  read, write
    value       4d495f5343414c45 | 'MI_SCALE'
   2a01 (Appearance)
    properties  read
    value       800c | ' '
  2a02 (Peripheral Privacy Flag)
    properties  read, write
    value       00 | ' '
  2a04 (Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters)
    properties  read
    value       6400c8000000d007 | 'd H   P'
  2a03 (Reconnection Address)
    properties  read, writeWithoutResponse, write
    value        | ''
  2a9d (Weight Measurement)
    properties  indicate
  00002a2f0000351221180009af100700
    properties  write, notify
  000015300000351221180009af100700
  000015310000351221180009af100700
    properties  write, notify
  000015320000351221180009af100700
    properties  writeWithoutResponse
  2a04 (Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters)
    properties  read, write, notify
    value       0c000c000000c800 | '    H '
  000015420000351221180009af100700
    properties  read, write, notify
    value       0301 | ''
  000015430000351221180009af100700
    properties  read, write, notify
    value       0100 | ' '
```

**but base this code :**

```js
'use strict';
const noble = require('noble');
let lastvalue = '';

noble.on('stateChange', state => {
  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    noble.startScanning(['181d'], true);
  } else {
    noble.stopScanning();
  }
});

noble.on('discover', peripheral => {
  let serviceData = peripheral.advertisement.serviceData,
    unit = '',
    newval = false,
    measured;
  if (serviceData && serviceData.length) {
    for (let i in serviceData) {
      if (serviceData.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        let data = serviceData[i].data.toString('hex');
        switch (data.substr(0, 2)) {
        case '03':
          unit = 'lbs';
          newval = true;
          break;
        case 'a3':
          unit = 'lbs';
          break;
        case '12':
          unit = 'jin';
          newval = true;
          break;
        case 'b2':
          unit = 'jin';
          break;
        case '22':
          unit = 'kg';
          newval = true;
          break;
        case 'a2':
          unit = 'kg';
          break;
        default:
          unit = '';
          break;
        }
        measured = parseInt(data.slice(4, 6) + data.slice(2, 4), 16) * 0.01;
        measured = unit === 'kg' ? measured / 2 : measured;
        if (unit) {
          if (lastvalue !== measured && !newval) {
            console.log('Last measured: ' + measured + ' ' + unit);
          } else if (newval && lastvalue !== measured) {
            console.log('New measure: ' + measured + ' ' + unit);
          }
          lastvalue = measured;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

i worked with serviceData variable and finally i got weight

But My Questions is
What is Simple Way to use This methods in C# ?
if i use noble i should install vs and node.js and noble and Zadig on any Users system and is too Complicate

another Questions , in recived data for example

> 2a03 (Reconnection Address)
>       properties  read, writeWithoutResponse, write

What are these properties and how should them be used?